# Not able to establish a connection over Socket.io in swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io` framework for swift. I am trying to connect via websockets API, I have a method, which is getting called in the `viewDidLoad` of the `ViewController`. I have declared my manager and the socketClient globally, i'll put the code for the method below:

```
private func setupSockets() {
    manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://kaboom.rksv.net")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    socket = SocketIOClient(manager: manager, nsp: "/watch")//manager.defaultSocket
    socket.onAny {print("Got event: \($0.event), with items: \($0.items)")}

        socket.on("data", callback: { (data, ack) in
        print(data)
    })

    socket.on("error", callback: { (data, ack) in
        print(data)
        print(ack)

    })


    socket.on("connect", callback: { (data, ack) in
        print(data)
        print(ack)


        self.socket.emit("ping", [])

    })

    socket.connect()
}
```

The issue I face is that the `connect` callback is not getting called and hence, I'm not able to emit a ping message. Here are the logs:

> 2018-02-18 19:02:20.589406+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketIOClient{/watch}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting]
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:20.589692+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketIOClient{/watch}: Joining namespace /watch
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:20.589850+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:20.589916+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:32.986354+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662271] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://kaboom.rksv.net
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:32.988480+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662271] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:32.995078+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662271] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://kaboom.rksv.net/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.197687+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.200976+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 97:0{"sid":"4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.208867+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.226824+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketManager: Engine opened Connect
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.226894+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://kaboom.rksv.net/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.227367+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.227447+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.230935+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.231392+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.231510+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST http://kaboom.rksv.net/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.280857+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.281066+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 2:40
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.281933+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.282346+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketParser: Parsing 0
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.283167+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662189] LOG SocketParser: Decoded packet as: SocketPacket {type: 0; data: []; id: -1; placeholders: 0; nsp: /}
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.283195+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662406] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://kaboom.rksv.net/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.330123+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662271] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: probe as type: 2
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.340044+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.340351+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 1:3
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.340621+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.341829+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://kaboom.rksv.net/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=4Uf21Mr7_9DGjSXcAASj
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.378473+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3probe
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.379059+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Received probe response, should upgrade to WebSockets
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.379252+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Upgrading transport to WebSockets
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.379368+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 6
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.379511+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:6
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.379968+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.477785+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.478016+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 1:6
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.478639+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 6
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.479275+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Switching to WebSockets
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.479594+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws:  as type: 5
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:33.480317+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Flushing probe wait
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:59.288327+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws:  has data: false
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:59.288576+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws:  as type: 2
>
> 2018-02-18 19:02:59.338827+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662407] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3
>
> 2018-02-18 19:03:26.788673+0530 stocks-cake[10965:3662679] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws:  has data: false

Is there anything i'm missing out? Something done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you solved it?

Comment: Declare the manager outside the scope of the method. I had an issue where the manager was getting released when the execution went out of the method.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar thank you so much buddy... you saved my days, i'm trying to fix this issue over 2 days, and finally i solved.

Comment: hi @shravan.sukumar did you find any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667702/8351061

Answer (score 1):

Declaration should look like this , you forget to set the port

```
   let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
   let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

Comment: I'm not running it in local. It is a third party server.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar are you getting solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace like below:

```
let socket = socketManager.socket(forNamespace: "/watch")
```