# ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, socket.io, swift5

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "Some url")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
var socket:SocketIOClient!
var name: String?
var resetAck: SocketAckEmitter?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    self.socket.on(clientEvent: .error) {data, ack in
        print("error")
    }

    self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .disconnect){data, ack in

        print("disconnect")

    }

    socket.connect()
    
    
}
```

ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request

LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Error"]

Comment: Check your server logs and when the swift-client connects look for a message, "The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols". If you see this message, update Socket.io-Swift-Client to the latest version. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

update pod to Socket.IO-Client-Swift 16.0.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Eman Gaber its work for me thanks

Answer (score 3):

So this problem gave me quite an agonizing 8-hour of digging and here are the steps I followed to solve the problem.

1. Check if you are using 'localhost:PORTNUMBER' as your URL. Instead, try using temporary 'https' using `ngrok` [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download).
2. If you insist on using http, try disabling `App Transport Security policy` in your project's info.plist
3. Check if you are using a compatible Client(iOS) and Server(Node js, and etc) Socket.io version. You can check compatibility table [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Usage%20Docs/Compatibility.md).

   - A simple fix is to drop server Socket.io version to 1.x.x.
   - to keep server Socket.io version to 4.x.x (current at the time of this writing) add `allowEI03: true` option when instantiating the server:

   ```js
     const io = new Server(httpServer, {
       allowEIO3: true
     });
   ```

   - If you are making a server using express I suggest this:

   ```js
     const express = require("app");
     const { createServer } = require("http");
     const { Server } = require("socket.io");
     const app = express();
     const httpServer = createServer(app);

     const io = new Server(httpServer, { 
       allowEIO3: true,
     });

     io.on("connection", (socket) => {
       // ...
     });

     httpServer.listen(3000);
   ```

Comment: Is the latest version of swift 16 and why is it 15 on github?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your package version to 16.0.1. This worked for me too!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).